# How do you add custom properties for ALL Azure Application Insight requests (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, azure, appinsights

- Given a browser Single Page Application
- When using AppInsights JS SDK v2.5.3
- Then I want a **CustomServiceName** to be sent with ALL   requests.

a) Should the custom properties be on the `envelope.data`, `env.data.baseData` or `envelope.data.properties` ?

It appears to change depending on the type of call made.

b) Can I set the `CustomServiceName` on the operation context instead of EVERY request instead?

Currently we are using this

```
        var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
            envelope.tags["ai.application.ver"] = "1.2.3";

            if (envelope.data) {
                envelope.data["CustomServiceName"] = "MyName";
                if (envelope.data.properties) {
                    envelope.data.properties["CustomServiceName"] = "MyName";
                }
            }
        };
        aisdk.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```

Based on https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#telemetry-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) `envelope.data` is the base of the model and setting new properties directly on this object may not be ingested properly, and `env.data.baseData` will vary depending on the type of data you send. `envelope.data.properties` should exist on all telemetry types and allows you to send whatever custom data along with your telemetry you wish. `envelope.data.properties["CustomServiceName"] = "MyName";` is the correct implementation.

b) Using a telemetry initializer is the best way to achieve this- adding a property to each request is one of the use cases for them. The context has [a small number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-context) of specific data points, and the list isn't customizable. Depending on the rest of your setup, Cloud Role may fit, but you will still need to use a telemetry initializer to set it.

Comment: Not sure if the SDK was updated or not. ```envelope.data.properties``` is now undefined, at least for ```pageView``` telemetry. While ```envelope.data.XXXX``` in Telemetry initializer is now automatically added to ```data.properties``` by inspecting the request sent by SDK

Comment: @Smokovsky just to be clear, this is the new approach?


`var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {

                envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "CLOUDROLEHERE";


                if (envelope.data) {

                    envelope.data["Name"] = aiName;

                    envelope.data["Email"] = aiEmail;

                    envelope.data["Role"] = aiRole;

                }

            };

            appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
`